Crepant morphisms and ramification formula.
In the context of studying the MMP from Kollar-Mori's "Birational geometry of aglebraic varieties" and Kollar's "Singularities of the minimal model program" I have some questions.
First what is the ramification formula and where can I find a reference for this ? We are using all the time that if we have a biraitonal morphism $f\colon Y \to X$ from a normal variety to a pair $(X,\Delta)$ we can write $K_Y+f^{-1}_*\Delta=f^{\ast}(K_X+\Delta)+\sum_Ea_EE$ and this even the definition of discrepancy in some cases. However I did not find in these books any clear statement of this. Moreover in Kollar's book the definition of a crepant morphism (2.6) we ask for similar relations between discrepancies and pullback. So any briational morphism is crepant ?
Secondly back the definition of crepant. If a morphism $f\colon Y\to X$ is crepant we get $a(E,Y,\Delta_Y)=a(E,X\Delta)$ for any divisor $E$ over $X$. This is the case in lemma 2.30 in Kollar-Mori's book. What is a divisor $E$ over $X$ in this context ? Are we considering $E\subseteq Y$ or another birational morphism $g\colon Z\to X$ ? But then how can we see $E$ as a divisor over $Y$?

What is the exact statement you're looking for a proof for? That $K_Y + f_^{-1}\Delta - f^(K_X + \Delta)$ is numerically/$\mathbb{Q}-$linearly equivalent to a unique $f$-exceptional divisor?

In my opinion, the definition of discrepancies you wrote above is discussed in most detail in the beginning of chapter 3 of this text, in that they spell out how representatives can be chosen for these a priori linear equivalence classes in order to have equality rather than numerical equivalence(which is what actually appears in Kollár-Mori) in your expression.

@Daniel Yes for example such a statement would be nice .I just don't understand how we can be using this without stating it clearly since it's pretty much necessary.  The text is nice but it goes a bit quickly on my question doesn't it ? It says that if we have  prime divisor $E$ in $D_Y$ its strict transform in $D_Z$ has the same coeff. Ok but what happens if $E$ is $f$-exceptional. So in my second question any exceptional divisor on $Z$ can be seen as an excpetional divisor on $Y$ ?

@Daniel Or is it that in $D_Y$ (resp $D_Z$) we're considering $f^{-1}*D$ (resp $g^{-1}*D_Z$) and the $f$-exceptional divisors (resp $g$), and somehow the $f$-exceptional divisors correspond to the $g$-exceptional with the same coeffcients ? But again why would this be true, we can consider the map $g^{-1}\circ f$and each strict transform of an $f$-exceptional divisor results in a $g$-exceptional divisor ?
